# Rolling 12/24 Month Average Price

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have been stuck on this logic for awhile and finally reaching out for help from the community. I am making a price variance chart that using the logic of:

Total Volume Previous Year - If the volume of the item in the past 12 months is NULL, meaning that the item was never sold then 0 ELSE

(Average Price of all transactions for that item in the last 12 months - Average Price of all transactions for that item in the last 13-24 months) X (Total Volume Current Year)

I tried to make a WITH advanced SQL query to break out the average price for the last 12 months and the months 13-24 prior to the current date however I don't think my WHERE statement is doing that:

```
SELECT

inv_item_mst.item,
AVG(inv_item_mst.price*(1-(inv_item_mst.disc/100))) AS [AvgPreviousPrice],
SUM(inv_item_mst.qty_invoiced) AS [PreviousVolume],
inv_hdr_mst.cust_num


FROM inv_item_mst

LEFT JOIN inv_hdr_mst
ON inv_item_mst.inv_num=inv_hdr_mst.inv_num

WHERE YEAR(inv_hdr_mst.inv_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()))

GROUP BY inv_item_mst.item,
inv_hdr_mst.cust_num
```

I replicated the same code using WHERE YEAR(inv_hdr_mst.inv_date) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,0,GETDATE())) to get the current volume and current average price.

Any idea on what I can change the WHERE to in order to track the average price and volume for all transactions BY ITEM that fall within the range of 0-11 months (Current) and 12-23 Months (Previous)?

NOTE : I also need to add logic that says if the item doesnt exist in the previous 12 months than I need it to be 0. I am joining the two queries with a master item table to ensure I get all of the items they are trying to track regardless of year.

Comment: What database is this? Please use the appropriate tags.

Comment: SQL code pulling from tables within SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not specify your desired output format, there are multiple solutions to your problem.

Also, your question contains some conflicting information about how you calculate your "rolling" average. Date ranges like [0-11] and [12,13] months will produce different results compared to working with the actual year value. The example below proves my point.

```
today              = 2020-07-22
current 12 months  = [2019-07-22, 2020-07-22] --> defined with dateadd(year, -1, ...)
current year       = 2020                     --> defined with year(...)-1
previous 12 months = [2018-07-22, 2019-07-21] --> defined with dateadd(year, -2, ...)
previous year      = 2019                     --> defined with year(...)-2
```

**Sample data**

Define table structures

```
declare @item table
(
    ItemId int,
    ItemName nvarchar(20)
);

declare @trans table
(
    ItemId nvarchar(20),
    TransDate date,
    TransVolume int,
    TransPrice money
);
```

Determine date ranges for sample data

```
select  convert(date,getdate()) as 'today',
        dateadd(year, -1, convert(date,getdate())) as 'start last year',
        dateadd(year, -2, convert(date,getdate())) as 'start last 2 years';


today       start last year  start last 2 years
----------  ---------------  ------------------
2020-07-22  2019-07-22       2018-07-22
```

Insert some sample data

```
insert into @item (ItemId, ItemName) values
(1, 'Awesome product'),
(2, 'Mega item'),
(3, 'Super stuff'),
(4, 'Weird thing'); -- will not be sold

insert into @trans (ItemId, TransDate, TransVolume, TransPrice) values
(1, '2017-01-01', 99, 9.99), -- before last 2 years, to be excluded
(1, '2019-01-01', 10, 1.20), -- in     last 2 years
(1, '2019-05-01',  7, 1.50), -- in     last 2 years
(1, '2019-06-01',  1, 1.00), -- in     last 2 years
(1, '2020-03-01',  8, 2.00), -- in     last 1 year
(2, '2019-03-01', 12, 0.75), -- in     last 2 years
(2, '2019-08-01',  3, 1.20), -- in     last 1 year
(2, '2019-10-01', 10, 1.20), -- in     last 1 year
(2, '2020-07-01',  9, 0.80), -- in     last 1 year
(3, '2019-04-01',  7, 1.20), -- in     last 2 years
(3, '2019-05-01', 11, 1.50), -- in     last 2 years
(3, '2020-04-01',  3, 0.80), -- in     last 1 year
(3, '2020-05-01',  2, 1.25); -- in     last 1 year
```

**Solution 1**

This solution presents the values of the various periods side by side (on the same row). There are two [outer apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#using-apply) subqueries for the two periods. The current and previous period are calculated with *date ranges*.

```
select  i.ItemName,
        isnull(calc1.SumVol, 0) as 'SumVolume1', -- volume in last 2 years
        isnull(calc1.AvgPri, 0) as 'AvgPrice1',  -- average price in last 2 years
        isnull(calc2.SumVol, 0) as 'Volume2',    -- volume in last 1 year
        isnull(calc2.AvgPri, 0) as 'AvgPrice2'   -- average price in last 1 year
from @item i
outer apply (   select  sum(t2.TransVolume) as 'SumVol',
                        avg(t2.TransPrice) as 'AvgPri'
                from @trans t2
                where t2.ItemId = i.ItemId
                  and t2.TransDate >= dateadd(year, -2, convert(date,getdate()))
                  and t2.TransDate <  dateadd(year, -1, convert(date,getdate())) ) calc1
outer apply (   select  sum(t1.TransVolume) as 'SumVol',
                        avg(t1.TransPrice) as 'AvgPri'
                from @trans t1
                where t1.ItemId = i.ItemId
                  and t1.TransDate >= dateadd(year, -1, convert(date,getdate())) ) calc2;
```

The result looks like this:

```
ItemName             SumVolume1  AvgPrice1             Volume2     AvgPrice2
-------------------- ----------- --------------------- ----------- ---------------------
Awesome product      18          1,2333                8           2,00
Mega item            12          0,75                  22          1,0666
Super stuff          18          1,35                  5           1,025
Weird thing          0           0,00                  0           0,00
```

**Solution 2**

This solution presents the values of the different periods underneath each other (different rows). It uses a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE) defined with the `with` keyword. You get a row with `null` for items without transactions (can be replaced with `isnull()`). The current and previous period are again calculated with *date ranges*.

```
with cte_TransRange as
(
    select  case
                when t.TransDate >= dateadd(year, -1, convert(date,getdate())) then -1
                when t.TransDate >= dateadd(year, -2, convert(date,getdate())) then -2
                else 0
            end as 'YearRange',
            t.ItemId,
            t.TransPrice,
            t.TransVolume
    from @trans t
)
select  i.ItemName,
        tr.YearRange,
        isnull(sum(tr.TransVolume),0) as 'SumVolume',
        isnull(avg(tr.TransPrice),0) as 'AvgPrice'
from @item i
left join cte_TransRange tr
    on  tr.ItemId = i.ItemId
    and tr.YearRange <> 0
group by    i.ItemName,
            tr.YearRange
order by i.ItemName;
```

This gives the same numbers in another format:

```
ItemName             YearRange   SumVolume   AvgPrice
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
Awesome product      -2          18          1,2333
Awesome product      -1          8           2,00
Mega item            -2          12          0,75
Mega item            -1          22          1,0666
Super stuff          -2          18          1,35
Super stuff          -1          5           1,025
Weird thing          NULL        0           0,00
```

**Solution 3**

A variant on solution 2, but instead of working with *date ranges* I now used the actual *year*. This version is a lot shorter (and simpler) because of that.

```
select  i.ItemName,
        year(t.TransDate) as 'Year',
        isnull(sum(t.TransVolume),0) as 'SumVolume',
        isnull(avg(t.TransPrice),0) as 'AvgPrice'
from @item i
left join @trans t
    on  t.ItemId = i.ItemId
    and year(t.TransDate) > year(getdate())-2
group by    i.ItemName,
            year(t.TransDate)
order by i.ItemName;
```

But this produces different results when compared to the previous numbers!

```
ItemName             Year        SumVolume   AvgPrice
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------
Awesome product      2019        18          1,2333
Awesome product      2020        8           2,00
Mega item            2019        25          1,05
Mega item            2020        9           0,80
Super stuff          2019        18          1,35
Super stuff          2020        5           1,025
Weird thing          NULL        0           0,00
```

Hope this solves your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Helped a lot!

Comment: @supahman You are welcome! If this solved your question, then you can mark my response as the accepted answer.